# Has anyone seen their 2007 custom css modified in a 2010 environment?

Tags: css

I am loading a logo image from the Style Library using the following css statement:

background:url("../Style Library/Images/LogoHeader.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;

When I deploy the same branding solution in a 2010 environment, this becomes:

background:url("../_vti_ghost/Images/LogoHeader.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;

Needless to day, this borks the branding and I can't find any reason for this happening nor can I find a reference to _vti_ghost anywhere on the internets.

Help?

Comment: how did you deploy the css?

Comment: Everything was deployed as part of WSP.

We ended recreating the solution in VS2010 which made this issue irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

How is your branding being deployed? It sounds to me like you're deployed a branded master page that's ghostable, so ../Style Library doesn't exist relative to the ghostable location of the master page. A better practice is to use /Style Library/images/logo.jpg, since relative to the root, that path will never change.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried removing the space between Style & Library as I believe it is rendered StyleLibrary and not Style[space]Library.